# why the function Write.fcs in the Flowcore package corrupts my FCS file

Tags: r

I am analyzing FCS files from a CyTOF experiment using Flowcore package
. When I import and export my FCS files using read.FCS and write.FCS, I find that these functions have corrupted my FCS file and all channels are affected and the data looks like the tSNE in the picture below (not what is expected or meaningful).

I'm using R (ver.3.6), Rstudio (1.2.1335), and flowcore ver.3.9.
Here is the code I have used:

```
library(flowCore)
#Import FCS file
myfilename<-"export_MIX_NT_Ungated_viSNE.fcs"   
myfile_fcs<-read.FCS(myfilename,
                  transformation="linearize", which.lines=NULL, 
                  alter.names=FALSE, column.pattern=NULL)

#I plan to do some data analysis here in the final version before exporting below
#export the fcs file and rename it to T_+filename
write.FCS(myfile_fcs,paste("T_",keyword(myfile_fcs)$"$FIL",sep=""), what="numeric")
```

and this is what the original file looks like before import into R

[image: before]

and this is what the exported result looks like after export

[image: after]

Here is the file that we have used for this code: [dropbox link for the example file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ydew7sk5ry1hn2v/export_MIX_NT_Ungated_viSNE.fcs?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

I've looked into your problem and at first I was skeptical about the transformation of read.fcs. Looking into your example file, I also see that there are already columns for your original (full plot) tsne plot, so I'm assuming flowjo is rewriting the tsne values after you read/write it into R. Since Flowcore is generally more targeted towards flow data and not cytof, I took a few pieces of [this Bioc2017 walkthough](https://www.bioconductor.org/help/course-materials/2017/BioC2017/Day2/Workshops/CyTOF/doc/cytofWorkflow_BioC2017workshop.html) and recreated the transformations, which seems to work better although I'm not sure how flowjo will handle the data now. If you were going to do more work on the data though, we now have it at an accessible low level so you can basically do whatever you want. Here's my code.

```
fcs_raw <- read.flowSet("~/Downloads/export_MIX_NT_Ungated_viSNE.fcs", transformation = FALSE, 
                    truncate_max_range = FALSE)
fcs <- fsApply(fcs_raw, function(x, cofactor = 5){
  expr <- exprs(x)
  expr <- asinh(expr[,] / cofactor)
  exprs(x) <- expr
  x
})

expr <- fsApply(fcs, exprs)

library(matrixStats)
rng <- colQuantiles(expr, probs = c(0.01, 0.99))
expr01 <- t((t(expr) - rng[, 1]) / (rng[, 2] - rng[, 1]))
expr01[expr01 < 0] <- 0
expr01[expr01 > 1] <- 1


expr01
summary(expr01)
```

Be aware that this does mess up your original tSNE column numbers, so if these were important to you, I would read the flowset, make a copy of those columns, and move on with the data analysis in the code. If you have future questions or analysis with flow data feel free to contact me directly.

Answer (score 0):

@csugai, thanks for your answer. The `truncate_max_range = FALSE` argument in the `read.flowSet` function caught my eyes so I included that into my `read.FCS` function and that fixed the problem! Although I didn't really understand other parts of your code that resulted in a binned data.